# MongoClient not working with php

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm trying to use mongodb with php but I keep getting this error

> ("Class 'MongoClient' not found")

whenever I try this code:

```
$m = new MongoClient();
```

The weird part is that if I run a `get_loaded_extensions()`, mongodb shows up and it also shows up on the `phpinfo()`. I also have `extension=mongodb.so` on the php.ini file.

I'm on debian running MongoDB shell version: 2.6.11 and php is running mongodb version  1.1.2.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: "Class 'MongoClient' not found"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing up the `Mongo`and `MongoDB` extensions.
The (deprecated) `Mongo` extension loads via `mongo.so` and provides `MongoClient`.
You're using the newer and preferred `MongoDB` extension (`mongodb.so`) so you should be using:

```
$client = new MongoDB\Client("mongodb://localhost:27017");
```

See: http://php.net/manual/en/set.mongodb.php
vs https://www.php.net/manual/en/mongo.setup.php

Comment: Now I get "Class 'MongoDB\Client' not found" =/

Comment: I found out in the documentation you put! It should be $client = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017");

Comment: Ah, the client library isn't automatically included. You should install that too: http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.tutorial.library.php

Comment: Ya, that worked too. Thansk a lot! .. Almost all the problem came from the fact that when doing a google search for "php mongodb", you actually get the deprecated extension (Mongo)