# ODM, ORM for php with MongoDB and how to connect

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm coming from Python using MongoDB with `pymongo` and `mongoengine`.

Which ODM/ORM is easiest to work with in php?  That probably means most similar to the Python ones I mentioned but I'm willing to use whatever is the most popular and has good community support.

As of now, I installed following instructions here: https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/php

And tried to test my mongodb connection following instructions here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mongo.tutorial.connecting.php

The script below does not show any of the users in the `user` collection.

```
<?php

echo "test mongodb connection";

$connection = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27107");

$db = $connection->cnf;

//collection
$users = $db->user;

//use cursor
$cursor = $users->find();
foreach($cursor as $id=> $value){
    echo "$id: ";
    var_dump($value);
}
?>
```

My MongoDB is up, I can type `mongo` in the terminal and get the Mongo shell and I have not changed the port.  My Python app can connect using mongoengine's `connect('cnf')` so I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haha, I'm in same boat.
After python PHP looking pretty terrible. :)
Silently returning `null` instead of exceptions is a usual PHP behavior.

At first, you are using deprecated driver.
[See this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35626360/mongoclient-not-working-with-php)

So, working code will be looking like

```php
<?php
echo "test mongodb connection\n";

$manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager('mongodb://localhost:27017');
$dbcol = new MongoDB\Collection($manager, 'db_name', 'collection_name');

$cursor = $dbcol->find();
foreach($cursor as $id => $value){
    echo "ID: $id\n";
    echo "Full data:\n";
    print_r($value);
}
?>
```